How can I get Meeting Transcript of any Meeting in my organization domain or other organization?
I have researched a lot how to get transcript of any meeting scheduled in my organization or out of the organization of any Microsoft Teams Meeting.
with other third-parties applications like Sana AI or Meetingtor they can easily fetch any meeting transcripts of Teams Meeting.
So, does anybody know how to do or what is the mechanism behind it?
Do I  need to depend on Microsoft Azure Services or is there alternative solutions?
I am curious on how other companies fetch transcript and recording.
Actually, I'm not able to fetch transcript within my organization.
Help ME!!!
I have tried to fetch transcript of Teams meeting but I'm not able to fetch transcript only when I'm the organizer of the meeting.
Using Graph API and Microsoft Graph Explorer.
Ref link: here

Thank you for your inquiry about your Teams app development issue. This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2115723/how-can-i-get-meeting-transcript-of-any-meeting-in. Please follow the above-mentioned thread for further updates.
